# how to change text based on condition in listview xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin forms and c#. I am using WCF web service. I am getting an List and want to check a condition and based on that condition i want to update the listview.
i have searched article, but founded nothing that i wanted.
till now i have done this.

```
IEnumerable<LoadTrackedEmployee> _trackedEmployee; 

    private void Client_LoadTrackingEmployeeCompleted(object sender, LoadTrackingEmployeeCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                var response = e.Result.ToString();
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LoadTrackedEmployee>>(response);

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {

                    _trackedEmployee = result as IEnumerable<LoadTrackedEmployee>;
                    employeeList.ItemsSource = _trackedEmployee;
                    foreach(var item in _trackedEmployee)
                    {
                        if(item.int_LastLogin==null)
                        {

                            // I am trying to change it here. I have given label x:name="status" and i am trying to do this
                           status.TextColor = "Red"; // for some reason this doesnt work
                        }else{ status.TextColor = "Green"; }
                    }
                });
            }
```

IValueConverter example

LoadTrackedEmployee.cs

```
public class LoadTrackedEmployee
    {

        public string vchar_UserGUID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "User ID")]
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Full Name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Official Email ID")]
        public string OfficialEmailID { get; set; }
        public int? int_LastLogin { get; set; }

    }
```

ListToColorConerter.cs

```
    public class ListToColorConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            #region IValueConverter implementation

            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
//What should i do here
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            #endregion
        }
```

XAML

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:StringToColorConverter x:Key="ListConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ListView x:Name="employeeList" 
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      SeparatorVisibility="Default"  
                      ItemSelected="employeeList_ItemSelected"
                      SeparatorColor="Black"
                      Margin="5,0,5,0">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label x:Name="status" BackgroundColor="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ListToColorConverter }}}" WidthRequest="3" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="0,2,0,2"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>        
    </ListView>
```

and i have also added local xmlns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would introduce additional property in the `LoadTrackedEmployee` which will return a boolean based on your condition. Than use `IValueConverter` while binding to this property which will return colour X if true or red colour if false.

Documentation:
[Binding Value Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters)
[From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)

**EDIT:**

Since now you slightly changed your question here is what you should have in `IValueConverter`:

```
public class ListToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is LoadTrackedEmployee)
            return (value as LoadTrackedEmployee).int_LastLogin.HasValue() ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can bind to `int_LastLogin` instead of the whole model.

P.S.: Please follow C# naming conventions.

Comment: i am trying out your answer...can you convert a list(a Model) 'code'public class LoadTrackedEmployee{public string vchar_UserGUID { get; set; }public int? int_LastLogin { get; set; }}

Comment: i am trying to use IValueConverter. This is what i have done... public class ListToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter implementation

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //what should i do here
        }
        #endregion
    }

Comment: Please post your code examples in the question itself and not in comments.

Comment: ok... i am sorry about that.. i am new to using stackoverflow

Comment: no problem, just that it is very hard to read code in comments.

Comment: We should chat about it https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168896/how-to-change-text-based-on-condition-in-listview-xamarin-forms

Comment: hi, I must have  20 reputation to join chat, would you like to chat somewhere else

Comment: and yes thats what i want to know

Comment: If you are happy with my answer please upvote or and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is your friend: [TextColor](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Label.TextColor/) of [Label](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Label/) class is of type  [Color](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Label.TextColor/), so you can either choose one of already finded colors:

```
status.TextColor = Color.Red;
```

or create your own one:

```
status.TextColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
```

If you want to have separate colors for each listview rows, you need to:

1) Define your listview as follows, so it contains bindings to name and color:

```
<ListView x:Name="employeeList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding DisplayName}" TextColor="{Binding Color}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

2) Create a viewmodel class for each row of your list:

```
  public class Employee
  {
    public string DisplayName {get;set;}
    public Color Color {get;set;}
  }
```

3) Create your actual viewmodels:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee> { new Employee { DisplayName = "John", Color= Color.Green } };
```

4) Attach your list as listview source:

```
employeeList.ItemsSource = employees;
```

I didn't test the code, but you should figure it out.

Comment: changed it to that.... but the problem is the **status** itself isnt identified by xamarin forms

Comment: thanks...it works... dont know why it wasnt working...i did exactly what you did